# How do I create a header using bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I am a react native developer and I need help with a project. The goal is to export PDF files from the mobile. The problem is I am not a web developer and the file has to be in HTML. The design looks like the attached photo. How do I accomplish this with Bootstrap?

Sorry for not having any sample code. I am not a web developer. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you can look at the [Bootstrap 4 Navbar documentation.](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/) For your use case, you probably need something like this:

Include Bootstrap CSS

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
```

Create a 'navbar' with the 3 elements you have in your screenshot

```
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Symptoms - Tom Jones</span>
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto">
      <img src="logo.svg" width="30" height="30" alt="">
    </a>
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Jan. 1, 2020 - Jan. 2, 2020</span>
  </nav>
</body>
```

This is a preview of what you get using the Bootstrap logo (obviously you can switch it out for your own):

[image: Preview]